# Can we define probability measure on all sigma algebras?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Can we define probability measure on all sigma algebras? ( or can we only define probability  measure on sigma alegras that equal to power set of given set?)

Comment: Yes, you can define a probability on every sigma algebra; often you take the power set but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can define a probability on every sigma algebra; often you take the power set but it's not necessary. For example in $\mathbb{R}$ you often take the Borel $\sigma$-field.